# In Java, when to write separate methods for different jobs - best practices?

Tags: java

I wrote a small [program](http://writtingplugin.blogspot.de/#!/2013/04/checking-ipv4-and-ipv6-addresses-with.html) that validates IP addresses, esp. strips off some metadata like range and network mask of an IP v4 address before passig it to the IPAddress Checker.

While stripping off the network mask of an IP address I need the resulting IP address (I call it the base IP address) and the network mask in separate variables, for further validation.

I was wondering if the way I did it in the cutOffNetMask method is ok or if I should split the jobs

1. extract base ip
2. extract the network mask

into separate methods?

Is the way I set the `private Integer netMask;` ìn the cutOffNetMask method the state of the art or how does the elegant way doing it looks like?

Here is the snippet:

```
public class IPAddress {

     private String base;
     private Integer netMask;
     private boolean ipRangeValid;
     private boolean netMaskValid;

 public IPAddress(String value){
     ipAddress = value;
     base = ipAddress;
     base.replace(" ","");

     if(isIPv6Address(base) == false){

       if(hasNetMask(base) == true){
          base = cutOffNetMask(base);
       }

       if(hasIPRange(base) == true){
          base = stripOffIPRange(base);
          ipRangeValid = ipRangeValid(octet1, octet2, octet3, octet4);
       } else {
            ipRangeValid = true;
       }
     }
 }

 private static boolean hasNetMask(String base){
     return (base.indexOf("/") != -1);
 }


  private static String cutOffNetMask(String base){
      netMask = base.substring(base.indexOf("/") + 1);
      return base.replace(netMask, "");
  }

  private String stripOffIPRange(String base){
      String[] octets = base.split("\\.");
      base = "";

      octet1 = new IPOctet(octets[0]);
      base = base + (octet1.getBase() + ".");

      octet2 = new IPOctet(octets[1]);
      base = base + (octet2.getBase() + ".");

      octet3 = new IPOctet(octets[2]);
      base = base + (octet3.getBase() + ".");

      octet4 = new IPOctet(octets[3]);
      base = base + (octet4.getBase());

      return base;
  }
```

Comment: It is always better to have separate methods for specific logic. This is called [Cohesion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_(computer_science)) (it applies to classes, but it can apply to methods too).

Comment: The question is when it's worth it. Should one write a separate method for the smallest jobs? When you look at my stripOffIPRange, it also does two jobs. Is this bad?

Comment: If you must reuse this method later somewhere else in your code, then you should. If your application would be as simple as is (of course, not a real world application), then that depends on you. But usually, it would be better to handle small jobs in different methods.

Comment: Additional note: if these small jobs don't mean anything if separated, then use them together.

Comment: What do I need to do to make this code "a real world application"? Does you refer to the size or what else can I improve? The only thing that comes into my mind is error handling.

Comment: To begin with, your `IPAddress` class has no way to communicate with other classes because all its methods are **private**, you need something to communicate to external classes *Hey, I did my job, want to know the results?*. And I don't mean having `System.out.println` (or similar) calls inside it.

Comment: That's only a snippet. The full code is here: http://writtingplugin.blogspot.de/#!/2013/04/checking-ipv4-and-ipv6-addresses-with.html

Comment: Is the way I set the private Integer netMask; ìn the cutOffNetMask method the state of the art or how does the elegant way doing it looks like?

Comment: You should buy [Code complete 2nd edition](http://www.cc2e.com). It worths its price since it is full of valued advises. Chapter 7 is  named "High Quality Routines" and answers this kind of questions.

Comment: @ClémentMATHIEU are you promoting the book or just putting it as suggestion?

Comment: f(hasIPRange(base) == true) is an unnecessary test f(hasIPRange(base)) is sufficient. To expand on @Luiggi Mendoza's answer. Your methods should do one thing and consistently. A good way of approaching this is to describe it's purpose (javadoc, method name, whatever). If it isnt concise, then maybe it needs decomposing. Good structure is a learnt skill, and improves with your understanding of the problem - it will emerge over time. Make it work. Prove it with tests. the rest will follow. Good luck!

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza It's a suggestion. I bought it several years ago and believe that any developer who ask questions like this one will find its content valuable. Unfortunately the is no excerpt of chapter 7 to support my claims.

Comment: @ClémentMATHIEU good to know, just remember that you should write a disclaimer when giving advice on using a commercial resource (API, book, etc) or the comment/answer could be deleted. Refer to [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) for more info.